# Agregar funcionalidades extras en Javascript. For Each, Map

Tags: javascript

tengo que agregar una funcionalidad a un codigo que ya escribi. La misma es una funcion  **listaDeVentas que devuelve una lista que contiene el precio de venta de cada auto vendido.**

Se me ocurre agregar el metodo de arrays FOR EACH pero seguramente no lo este codeando bien o quiza no sea la opcion correcta. Copio el codigo:

```
let autos = [{
    marca: "Ford",
    modelo: "Fiesta",
    color: "Azul",
    precio: 150000,
    km: 200,
    cuotas: 12,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: "APL123",
    vendido: true
},{
    marca: "Toyota",
    modelo: "Corolla",
    color: "Blanco",
    precio: 100000,
    km: 0,
    cuotas: 14,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: "JJK116",
    vendido: true
}];

const concesionaria = {
   autos: autos,
   buscarAuto: function(patente){
      for(let i = 0;i<autos.length;i++){
         if(autos[i].patente == patente) {
            return autos[i];
         }
      }
      return null;
},
venderAuto: function(patente){
   if(this.buscarAuto(patente) != null){
      let index = autos.indexOf(this.buscarAuto(patente));
      autos[index].vendido = true;
      }
},  
autosParaLaVenta: function(patente){
return autos = this.autos.filter(function (elemento){
      return !elemento.vendido
   })

},
autosNuevos : function(autos){
 return auto = this.autosParaLaVenta(function(elemento){

     if (auto.km<100){
         return autos.km
     }
 });

},           

listaDeVentas:function(precio){

    let ventaTotal=[150000,100000]
        ventaTotal.forEach(function(precios){
        
        })
    }
}
```

El rerror que me da:

- Al llamar a la función listaDeVentas debe retornar una lista con los precios de las ventas, la lista original debe devolver una lista vacia
- Al vender al auto con patente 'JJK116' y luego llamar a la función listaDeVentas debe contener el precio del auto vendido

Comment: No explicas el error sino lo que deseas obtener.

Comment: @Juan si si, coloque al final el error que me marca por el cual no me deja avanzar. Por lo que dice ahi, no me esta retornando el precio del auto vendido

Comment: Lee [ask]: procura ser más específico tanto en el título como en el cuerpo de las preguntas. Leyendo tus preguntas anteriores como esta misma, es difícil detectar de una cuál es el problema que estás teniendo. Además, lo que describes no son errores, sino lo que deseas obtener. Menciona tanto lo deseado como _lo obtenido actualmente_ (lo que hace que sea un problema).

Answer (score 1):

para devolver la lista de precios de autos vendidos implementa la siguiente función:

```js
listaDeVentas: function () {
    const vendidos = this.autos.filter(x => x.vendido);
    const precios = vendidos.map(x => {
      return {
        patente: x.patente,
        precio: x.precio
      }
    })

    return precios;
  }
```

Al final te va devolver lo que le indiques en el map, en este caso la patente y los precios (para que sepas a que objeto pertenece cada precio) ahora, si necesitas solo el precio quita el key patente.